# Simple Time Complexity Calculation

Tags: c#, time-complexity

I am new to Time Complexity, and now started solving problems,
I am not sure about whether I am correct, pleash tell me if I do, and if not,
how you calculated it.

[image: This is the problem]

I calculated the worst case as `6n+5`, and general case as `O(n)`, is it correct?

Comment: For future reference: O(6n+5) is the same as O(n). You remove all constants, because they take constant time!

Comment: This does not belong to java nor c++, only c# (due to Random class). Also, you should have written the code, not pasted an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the most commonly executed instruction.  It's `num = Random.Next (100)` (tied with some others).  How often is it executed?  N times; it's O(N).

You can also frequencies of other instructions.  We'll see that it doesn't matter.  If you do, you get O(6N+5), or something similar (I'll take your count since it doesn't matter).

If you have things added together, keep only the biggest one (when N is large). When N is large, 6N > 5, so you just keep O(6N).

Discard constant multipliers.  So you keep N and get O(N).

We discard all but the biggest for large N, because we only care about what happens for large N.  For large N, the smaller things become insignificant.

We discard constant multipliers because we don't care about the precise # of instructions, but just:  when you double the size of N, what happens to the time?  When we triple, quadruple, what have you, the size of N, what happens?  Whether it's multiplied by 6 or any other constant won't matter for that -- so we discard constant multipliers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. It is in `O(n)` since you iterate the for-loop `n` times. Assignments and declarations are `O(1)` - constant.

I don't know where you have taken `6n + 5` from. The first three lines are done only once. With worst case the loop is iterated n times and each number is bigger that the parameter. So you have `4*O(1)`. Since the last statement is out of the loop it is executed also only once. In total `3 + 4*n + 1 = 4n + 4`. The dominating term is `4n`, remove constants and you get `O(n)` time.

By dominating term is meant that for `n` to infinity, it really doesn't matter if you multiply it by `2,3,4` or divide it by some other number and that of course holds for some very big number, since there is no infinity with computers.